# Play!framework; Compile on server only instead on client

Tags: eclipse, playframework, java

Is it possible to compile my Play!framework application only serverside?

Since I **connect** a samba **share to my client** from the server hosting Play!, the **paths differ** between client and server (modules, play, libs). So eclipsify gives me the server paths on my client, instead of using the client paths. Due to this the client gives me a **build error**.

Solution would be;

- Change the eclipsify paths **per client configuration**.
- Only **compile** my app **on the server** (preferred since there'll be no differences in env settings).

Can anyone tell me how one of these options would be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [play-maven](http://www.playframework.org/modules/maven-head/home) plugin? Using maven for dependency management means all developers will have the same pom/config file, on running a maven build jars/libs will be downloaded from the repository server (you can use your own repo server too).

Answer (score 0):

why don't you install paly framework in the client? this framework is for development tasks so you should install it in your development machine (client i presume). Play framework is freely downloadable and easy to install on your client.

Comment: My server is my development environment. My client just has the IDE. And besides that it would be preferable to be able to work with multiple people on the same project. If each client would checkout a different version of the app, with different versions of Java and different env settings it would get messy real soon. I'd like to keep it on the server, so everyone uses the same env and settings for compiling/testing. Is this possible?

Comment: yes i see what you mean. it seems a good development decision but i don't know if it is possible to set up a dev environment on server and have many developers share same dev env. that would be a great advantage yet i doubt it is possible to do it with play!.the command line play commands will likely be executed on server i.e the machine where play is installed. may be play was designed not to be used in a distributed environment.the designer of the play framework knows better how play! works internally and if it can be used in a distributed environment.sorry if i could'nt help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a temp "solution" to let each client define its own path (probably will be overwritten by play eclipsify? Can I change this?).

In Eclipse I've added a variable called PLAY_HOME under Window > Preferences > Java > Build path > **Classpath Variables** pointing to "D:\play-1.2.2" in this case.

In the .classpath I've **replaced all absolute paths**:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/usr/local/bin/play-1.2.2/framework/lib/...jar" />
```

to:

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="PLAY_HOME/framework/lib/...jar"/>
```

Still no compilation on the server/continious integration etc. but it's a working solution for now, though it could be improved (the client - server diff dependencies still exists).

- Would be nice to **check** if the **version** of play matches
- Would be nice to make the PLAY_HOME **variable optional** by defaulting it to '..' (parent dir)

Comment: Now that I think of it, it would be much wiser to use version control and checkout the project per developer/client, and add a configuration to it (ignored by version control), possible by locally run play eclipsify. Only thing I'd really like is to force certain dependencies like JDK1.6.0_24 etc. Is this possible?

Comment: I slightly altered the method posted above. I now put the jars into a User Library in Eclipse. Still not sure how to do the version(dependency)check on Play! though.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an [Ant script](http://www.playframework.org/modules/antify-1.0/home) is what you need?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to develop with multiple developers on a single instance of an application hosted on some server???

It's maybe not the answer you're looking for, but my advice: **don't do it this way**.

Developing directly on a server, especially with multiple developers, is one of the great anti-patterns in development. Typically, only beginners and rather non-professional developers (no offense meant) do their development this way.

Restarting the server, debugging code, working in the same files... it only ends in tears when doing this 'shared' development.

Make sure you can run the application completely isolated on each workstation. Use version control to check in changes. If two developers have been working on the same code, you at least have a chance to rectify the situation (and a rather good chance if you use e.g. Mercurial or Git). If you still want to a global server to e.g. demo changes to non-developers, just periodically check-out a snapshot from version control and deploy that to this server.